# jQuery - The Routes are Correct, Yet the Alert Does Not Happen?

Tags: jquery

**The index.html File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Headline Tags Here</h1>
</body>
    </html>
```

**The script.js File:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("Hello!");


)};
```

**The Directory Called "lightbox":**

```
index.html
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
script.js
```

**The URL:**

```
http://localhost/lightbox/
```

I have tried loading the jquery files through the way you can see above and then I have tried to check this with an "alert" to see if it works. Though on page load the alert does not happen.

What is the issue here?

Comment: use browser console network tab to see if files are actually loading and to see if any errors are thrown

Comment: Next time if you're not sure if the path is wrong or the code is wrong, try this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead of linking to your local jquery file. This should leave you only with the latter posibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've written the ready function wrong.

rewrite to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("Hello!");


}); //issue was here. i changed ')}' to '})'
```

You should put the last brace before the parentheses

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did.

Answer (score 1):

The closing tag in not proper try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello!");
});
```